# Play audio files continuously with touch movements in iPhone

Tags: iphone, touch, avaudioplayer, fadein, fadeout

I'm trying to play continuous audio clippings when touch moves across the screen of iPhone. There are specific audio clippings according to the screen regions. When touch changes its region the previous audio fades out & the new clip (of the new region) fades in.
In `- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` method I'm detecting the region change & calling the `[self playSoundForRect]` method. Here is the method:

```
-(void)playSoundWithPath
{
    [self fadeVolume];
    NSString *audioPath;
    switch (curRect) // curRect is the Currently entered region
    {
        case 1:
            audioPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"clip1" ofType:@"mp3"];
            break;
        case 2:
            audioPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"clip2" ofType:@"mp3"];
            break;
        case 3:
            audioPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"clip3" ofType:@"mp3"];
            break;
        case 4:
            audioPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"clip4" ofType:@"mp3"];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioPath] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];
}

-(void)fadeVolume
{  
    if (theAudio.volume > 0.1)
    {
        theAudio.volume -= 0.1;
        [self performSelector:@selector(fadeVolume) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];           
    }
    else
    {
        [theAudio stop];
    }
}
```

But the code is not working properly. How to properly mix the in & out clips, so that they feel smooth & continuous? Any kind of suggesion is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try building a mixer for raw audio and use RemoteIO instead of the AVPlayer API to stream the mix.

Comment: Thanks for the response. RemoteIO is a bit complex, rather I'm using OpenAL.